# Redis Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

Using celery with redis in my django app
Everything was working fine until I ran into a problem. The location of the redis files was changed and redis could not access them. After searching, it turns out that this is due to random attacks on the Internet, and it is necessary to add confg
After I added the file, they both worked fine for a while, and then this problem appeared

```
1:S 25 Jun 2021 00:48:12.029 # Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused
1:S 25 Jun 2021 00:48:12.901 * Connecting to MASTER 194.38.20.199:8886
1:S 25 Jun 2021 00:48:12.902 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 25 Jun 2021 00:48:13.034 # Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused
1:S 25 Jun 2021 00:48:13.907 * Connecting to MASTER 194.38.20.199:8886
1:S 25 Jun 2021 00:48:13.908 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 25 Jun 2021 00:48:14.041 # Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused
```

**When I rebuild the Redis container it runs for a very short time and I get the same problem**

**settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get("redis://redis:6379/0")
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get("redis://redis:6379/0")
```

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
     redis:
      image: 'redis:alpine'
      restart: unless-stopped
      command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      volumes:
        - ./docker/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      ports:
        - '6379:6379'


  celery:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/backend/Dockerfile_celery
    entrypoint: /app/docker/backend/celery-entrypoint.sh
    environment:
      - some env vars
    depends_on:
      - asgiserver
      - redis
```

---

**redis.conf**

```
    bind 0.0.0.0 
    protected-mode yes
    rename-command CONFIG ""
```

Comment: You believe this is caused by someone maliciously connecting to your redis instance and changing the settings?

Comment: I did not mean the error mentioned above It was the error mentioned here https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/3594                                                                                                                     `Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused` This error I do not know the cause

Comment: Does your redis instance need to be accessible to anything other then your other compose services? If not then you could replace the `ports` config with `expose` so that it's only accessible by other services in the compose network

Comment: I don't think this error is due to someone changing any settings because I disable the CONFIG command, even for local users.
Anyway I will try this

Comment: @IainShelvington could you explain how that solves the problem? It did solve for me as well, but would like to understand how exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solved by change `ports` config with `expose`  as **Iain Shelvington** mentioned above

```
   redis:
      image: 'redis:alpine'
      restart: unless-stopped
      command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      volumes:
        - ./docker/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      expose:
        - 6379
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this setting to **slave** **redis.conf** file.

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30961240)